# How to Format a Carbon Date to get the Full Month

Tags: php-carbon

I am using this code:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($quotation[0]->created_at)->format('d M Y')
```

The output is:

> 10 Mar 2016

I want:

> 10 March 2016

I have looked at the Carbon docs and googled high and low, and I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($quotation[0]->created_at)->format('d F Y')
```

By the way, I found it in php date docs, Carbon uses it to generate date.
https://www.php.net/manual/function.date

Answer (score 3):

```
$date1 = '2020-03-05'; 

$date2 = Carbon::parse($date1)->format('F j, Y');

dd($date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be used, if you wish to have the full month name in the date:

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($client[0]->event_date_from)->format('d F Y')}}
```

Use **f** instead of **M** in the *format* function.