# Changing date format in my template PhpWord

Tags: laravel, date-format, phpword

I'm trying to chnge the output of my date format in my template PhpWord but it doesn't work.
In my Controller I have:

```
public function edit(Attestationstagiaire $attestationstagiaire, $downloadName = null)
{
    $id = $attestationstagiaire->id;
    $desc1 = Attestationstagiaire::find($id);

    $my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(public_path('templates/stagiaire/attestation.docx'));

    $my_template->setValue('id', $desc1->id);
    $my_template->setValue('prenoms', $desc1->prenoms);
    $my_template->setValue('nom', $desc1->nom);
    $my_template->setValue('date_de_naissance', $desc1->date_de_naissance);
    $my_template->setValue('lieu_de_naissance', $desc1->lieu_de_naissance);

    try{
        $my_template->saveAs(storage_path("Document.docx"));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        //handle exception
    }
    return response()->download(storage_path("Document.docx"));

}
```

In the line -> $my_template->setValue('date_de_naissance', $desc1->date_de_naissance);
My date format in the output document shows **12-07-2020** but I want to have **12 Juillet 2020**.
How can I do?
Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126053/10573560):

```
-> $my_template->setValue('date_de_naissance',
Carbon\Carbon::parse( $desc1->date_de_naissance)->format('d F Y'))
```

more details in:

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php

Comment: Many Thanks OMR. It's working finally with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `format()` method to format the date.

You have to call the format() method on the date/timestamp instance (variable):

```
$desc1->date_de_naissance->format('j F Y');
```

Comment: Thank you OMi Shah. But it lacks the carbon